# Complex firestore query from pluralsight example does not work

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

This is probably a very basic question. I am following along with the code from a pluralsight course. Everything worked until I tried the following query:

```
$('#yearsOfExperienceFilter').click(function () {
    employeesRef
       .where("yearsOfExperience", ">=", 8)
       .where("yearsOfExperience", "<=", 36)
    employeesRef
       .where("gender", "==", "Female")
       .onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
            LoadTableData(querySnapshot);
        });
});
```

The results are always whichever part of the query is specified last. In this case, I get all employees who are female. If I switch the order of the query, I get the range of employees with years of experience between 8 and 36 (but not the females, for some reason). However, I never get the combined result of female employees with the specified years of experience. I created an index for the query in firestore and it is enabled, but still the results are not correct.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Removing the extra `employeesRef` in the middle:

```
$('#yearsOfExperienceFilter').click(function () {
    employeesRef
       .where("gender", "==", "Female")
       .where("yearsOfExperience", ">=", 8)
       .where("yearsOfExperience", "<=", 36)
       .onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
            LoadTableData(querySnapshot);
        });
});
```

Comment: Yes, that was the solution. The instructor specifically said we needed to use the reference again because we were including different properties in the query. I like this way better. Thank you JRL!